# Is this "not a header-name" well-formed C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following snippet.

```
#define X iostream>
#include <X
```

After `#include`, the [longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#pptoken-3.3) is `<`, and it is followed by an identifier. This identifier is replaced during preprocessing with `iostream>` and the directive, after all replacements, matches [the form](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp#include-2) `< h-char-sequence >`. As such, the program should be well-formed.

On the other hand, [lex.phases](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#phases-1.3) states:

> A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment.

As far as I can tell, the program above does *not* end in a partial preprocessing token. However, [the footnote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#footnote-10) states:

> A partial preprocessing token would arise from a source file ending in the first portion of a multi-character token that requires a terminating sequence of characters, such as a *header-name* that is missing the closing `"` or `>`.

This is confusing me. Can a source file end in a *header-name* that is missing the closing `>`?

It seems that msvc and gcc each treat the snippet [differently](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHOaxWDQhANQAGjtO48SYrCax2CYaAIIbwcjeWDvnbntX1xwLtJwArLx%2BHC0pFQnDc1msOwUSxWmGeZliPFIBE0nwWAGs4rEAHSxXF4/H4gBs%2Bk4kn%2BKOBnF4ChAGiRKIWcFgMEQKFQLASdGi5EoaA5XJiwC4ZmaWAAbnhVgA1PCYADuAHkEoxOIiaLQCNEaRAIhSIsFagBPVW8fXMYiGhURbQVZHcXh8tiCBUMWjGwG8LARLzANxiWg0%2B2kLAsQzAcQe4N4E6VMWYQNAzCqCpeTUm8iCVoU2h4CLEI0eLAUgjEPAsE0LKgGYAKGXypUqoP8QQiMTsKQyQSKFTqSO6ZoGIwocGWfS5mmQBaoBLtQMAWnG6HOABFTJZrGYNDs51Q0AxVjOFHP8ExgAxko5kEesDOECuzLxUHHiKWsBOIAtypVnBBXCM/JIAAcpCBFMRQlNkySpAI/4gEBiRQe0PTgf0YytLaVQTLB8Ffu0nR1MhfQxGMWGeI0cHAeMXSETMxGftCqwSF8vzkpGIIcDsqiAYSc6EpIOzAMgyA7MKWJcDsEC4IQJBwgicy8HaWhzOimI4gS6m4sS3wcGSpDlj8dIAkC7HUrS9IeoyLIQEgSwEAkqY8hAfKcvQxChKwaxcTxfECUJIlmGJvCYPgRCvnozbCKI4gdhF3ZqBS/akHK%2BYJBWJIcH8pBGY%2BnAKqm9kEDsqBUJx3G8fxgnCaJ4kQB4/KubJXDyeZSkLAgpxYDEH7pbp%2BmGRSJm2GZimoqQGKSBoWJmAA7PCZhmD8ACc00/LE3EDpwsSscZVItZ8pBMlAVlIM5AqOadrkgGKyAJAkAD6YpcItd0GJq4x3aofHBpgErSrKirKgCap0JqxDarqkZmka6ZQxaVo2g46aOowBAum6FJej6fq0AG6YhmGEZAvgMaOHGCZBcmyCpmsiLBJq2lAjmeYFhgaxAiWZZpVWp61v9DZA7wEWttF0ixUo8V9iAZj6GGw7rqOTPvlOM5pIGAD0i5y1Ylibo%2Bz6vvG8Cfuh35%2BL%2BDDuGRowgRbNEQc0OTQekVtNAhuRpHbqEtG0mFdLBaE%2BwI%2BGTIURF6FRwwu%2BHEye3RizLIxTXpZl2WUhxn38SwCjXTsj2LVir3xoVkkhTJGxNQpDIqbiakaQSPW8H1WUDbtNJ0iNlnwNZIC2QV53si50TuWwnAZzsWc53nBdMG9BBBaXYXNELUXtqLshxb2QK6NLyVMKl9rMRl205RweV2amRUlWPE/CVPhfjBJdWD8QslmM1HdtR1/TddpvUgAZzc2Kt2GlXMaUtCQ4kWpIWIkgJqEkWsKQCGhJDS20ltQBO0OCVwsofB8GCT7YNaqQZ8KRnCSCAA%3D).

Comment: So the closing `>` is missing, so it isn't valid, according to your own citation. Why anyone would ever perpetrate such an abomination is another mystery.

Comment: I think it's a bug in standard. It explicitly permits macros in `#include` directive (including macros like this), but then the part you quoted says this entire file is invalid (before we even reach macro expansion). So it would be valid if you have anything at all after that include (say, empty comment), but not valid as is.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think that your comment above along with the now deleted answer to explain why it should be ok if the file didn't end like that would be a good answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I changed my mind four times now and I'm still not 100% sure about the interpretation. I rewrote my answer and undeleted it, but I still feel my above comment may also be a reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this code is valid. [[lex.phases]#1.10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#footnote-10) (the footnote to [[lex.phases]#1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex#phases-1.3)) does not apply here. We don't have `header-name` here, we have sequence `#include pp-tokens new-line` as per [cpp.include#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp.include#4) and it is valid and complete token<sup>1</sup> (as long as the newline is there).

To be honest, I'm not sure how the partial preprocessing token could look like in the case of `#include` directive - the only thing would be missing newline, because `pp-tokens` match almost anything. This seems like unexpected interaction or a result of a change at some point.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: the behaviour is undefined if after macro expansion this will not be a valid `#include` directive.

Comment: Missing newlines are rectified in [lex.phases/2]. Consider `#include <"`. Since double-quote by itself is not a valid pp-token, this would only match the header-name grammar, except that it is incomplete. This is the best I could come up with.

Comment: h-char is any source char except for new-line and >, and most sequences of those can form a sequence of valid pp-tokens except in some of the composite cases like strings and characters... so e.g. `#include<"\"` is another case because `"\"` cannot match the string-literal grammar.

Comment: @JeffGarrett All of these still can form a sequence of complete preprocessing tokens, with `"` matching a single-character non-whitespace preprocessing token. However, if any `"` or `'` is lexed as that category, the program has undefined behavior already per https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#2.sentence-4.

Comment: I concede you are right! I find it a little unintuitive to allow the parse into pp-tokens that then immediately cause UB vs failing to match that possibility... but the wording fits better. In that case, I can't think of any example.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Small correction: It is ill-formed now as per the text in the link I posted. It was (weirdly) UB until very recently. However the non-whitespace single character tokens have existed since C++98, as has the rule on partial preprocessing tokens. I also don't know what situation it was supposed to cover.